# how to check if product belongs to particular category?

Tags: category-products

I want to check if product belongs to particular category then that product should be stored in that newly created category named folder.

I tried this code:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category);
$cats = $productCollection->getCategoryIds(); 
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
     $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
     $catname = $_cat->getName();    
     if (count(array_intersect($catname == 'Camera',$productCats))) {
         $dispretionPath='/Camera';
     } else {               
         $dispretionPath='/images' ;         
     }
}
```

--edit--

I tried this code but it is not creating folder

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($product as $products) {
   if (array_search($category_id == 3,$products) === false ) {
    $dispretionPath='/Camera';
}else {             
            $dispretionPath='/images' ;      
        }
} 
return $dispretionPath;
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should not base your search on the category names since they can be changed or different on store views. Use the ids.
You can get the ids of the categories associated to a product like this:

```
$product->getCategoryIds()
```

Then check if your category id is in the result of the line above.

Comment: its not working